# Can't find an assembly matching the version that isn't set in config tells it a different version which exists

Tags: c#, nuget

The error I'm getting is:

```
Can't load file or assembly System.Web.Http 5.2.3.0
```

Even though in my web.config file it says

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.6.0" newVersion="5.2.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

and I've checked the dll in the bin folder and its version is 5.2.6.0 so where is it getting 5.2.3.0 from?

Comment: What about that answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32541088/1714342

Comment: Try to reinstall the Nuget-Package, the dependencies will eventually be fixed with this.

`Update-Package System.Web.Http -reinstall`

Answer (score 0):

Please try uninstalling and installing the package reference.

Also, please check if you are using the System.Web.Http reference in any of the projects loaded into build cycle of your project. If there check the version in the references section and change the reference as applicable.

The issue is most likely do to the above cause as I had faced a similar issue in a custom reference which I had in my solution. Please try and let me know.